# Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" is not working and icons are not showed up

Tags: .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

this code inside .htaccess file but still icons are not showed up in website. I checked everythink.

also i have on the top of index.php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

[image]

> also i see in page headers like that in chrome
> [image]

> but icons are still like that

[image]

Comment: The "icons" are presumably from the font being requested? Are you trying to load this font from a different host? "also i have on the top of index.php" - although that obviously won't apply to the font file that is being requested (from your domain I assume). Please edit your question to include the complete HTTP response headers for whentis font file is requested.

Comment: fonts are in my local and called inside the style.css they were imported as follow "src: url("fonts/font-icons.woff2") format("woff2");"

Comment: actually it works last night. But when i woke up fonts are missing. Nothing changed before last night. So i don't understand what was happening. I assume it is about cache or something but i put no-cache values to header. But still i coudn't do that. So how can i force to apply allow-origin to SUBFOLDERS by .htaccess

Comment: "fonts are in my local and called inside the style.css" - all "local" on the same server? However, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is only relevant if the requested hostname and origin are _different_? You shouldn't be blocked if the two are the same (regardless of whether this header is present or not). This refers to the two _redacted_ items in your screenshot. The response headers you have added don't refer to this font request.

Comment: Yes ALL MY FILES IN LOCAL... I'm asking "what could be went wrong ?" i need possibilities ? e.g. "did you checked output caches ?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that litespeed caching my .htaccess file so my changes didn't applied. So i disabled litespeed cache inside .htaccess file

```
<IfModule LiteSpeed> 
CacheDisable public /
</IfModule>
```

after i realized that i forgot output caches on my views. I closed them by adding

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

and after all that i put

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

in to my .htaccess. And then everything worked fine...